# getJobNames() in quartz scheduler 2.2.1

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We are upgrading from quartz scheduler release `1.8.6` to `2.2.1`.

In `1.8.6` we did this:

```
String[] jobs = sched.getJobNames(Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP);
```

How do I achieve this in `quartz scheduler 2.2.1`?

I have tried the `GroupMatcher` thing, with a `TriggerKey` match and the `sched.getTriggerKeys`, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In quartz 2.0.x a `GroupMatcher` class was introduced. So, to get job keys you should write something like this:

```
scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP))
```

Have a look at GroupMatcher javadoc: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/matchers/GroupMatcher.html

By the way, there is a comprehensive migration guide from 1.8.x to 2.x on Quartz-Scheduler site: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/migration-guide.html